# array multidimensional

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I study Java and I build a program with array:

```
com[0]="one";
com[1]="two";
com[2]="three";
[...]
com[9]="ten";
```

Every string of array is a commandment (my program is The 10 Commandment).

I'd like check if a commandment is already read. So, I think use a multidimensional array with string array and boolean array.

Is it possibile? What is the best way to do this?

thanks!

Comment: an array can't have two different types, have a look at hashmap

Comment: You can keep them separately in 2 arrays, same index referring to the same pair. Or you can define a new class and create an array of such object of that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a multidimensional array here, this only adds complexity. You just need a class Commandment:

```
public class Commandment {

   private String commandment;
   private boolean read;

   public Commandment(String commandment) {
      this.commandment = commandment;
   }

   public void setRead(boolean read) {
      this.read = read;
   }

   public boolean isRead() {
      return this.read;
   }
}
```

Then you create an array of Commandments:

```
com[0]= new Commandment("one");
com[1]= new Commandment("two");
com[2]= new Commandment("three");
```

To change to 'read':

```
com[2].setRead(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a separate array, same length and the indexes of that relate to those in your String array.

Probably a better way is to create an object like

```
public class Commandment {
    private String com;
    private String read;
    public (String com) {
        this.com = com;
        this.read = false;
    }
    public getCom() {
        return com;
    }
    public isRead() {
        return read;
    }
    public beenRead() {
        read = true;
    }
}
```

And make an array of those objects instead.

```
Commandment[] coms = new Commandment[10];
coms[0] = new Commandment("com1");
System.out.println(coms[0].getCom()+", has been read? "+coms[0].isRead());
coms[0].beenRead();
System.out.println(coms[0].getCom()+", has been read? "+coms[0].isRead());
```

Will create it, put in the first commandment as "com1" and then check if its been read, make it read, and check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use two collections

```
String[] commandments="zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten".split(",");
BitSet read = new BitSet(commandments.length);
```